# noflo browser component have project or graph id?

Tags: noflo

i am creating noflo project and need o get project or graph id inside the component

here is a simple component code

```
noflo = require 'noflo'

exports.getComponent = ->
  c = new noflo.Component
  c.inPorts.add 'in', (event, payload) ->
    return unless event is 'data'
    # Do something with the packet, then
    c.outPorts.out.send payload
  c.outPorts.add 'out'
c
```

is any event or any noflo object have project id 
or any noflo class having it so i include that one

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoFlo components being executed have no knowledge of the graph or project they are being executed in. This encapsulation is an important part of the component-based approach in FBP. To get access to an identifier, you should send it as an IIP on an inport (like any other piece of data needed by component).